# What is more efficient or correct in java servlets - Passing data with Cookies or Parameters using HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java

I am working on a project, and this question bothers me a lot.
I am using multiple servlets that some of them use the same data,
so i'm passing it through java script files, so in the servlets it looks like:

```
Parameter = request.getParameter("Parameter");
```

I am thinking of passing this data using Cookies, but i don't know what is more efficient, 
or correct programming.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a matter of efficiency; it's persistence.

I don't think cookies should be your first choice.  I'd prefer passing them via GET or POST as parameters.

Not all users allow cookies, so you might be breaking your app.

My question would be: Why do multiple servlets need the same information?  Why isn't it submitted once, persisted in a database, and accessed in read only fashion by all who need it?

Comment: The information i'm using is a user's id, or a unique identifier for every user. I need this identifier in some servlets, because their responsiblity is different - one servlets gets data "A" of this user, other servlets gets data "B" of this user and so on.                     I need this identifier to "travel" along the way with the flow of the app.

Comment: Then there ought to be a front controller servlet that mediates between all of them.  It's a pattern that's been with us since Struts 1.0.  And "travel" suggests "session" to me.  I don't like the sound of your design at all.  It gets worse the more you type.

Comment: I would also suggest that organizing your servlets by use case rather than data would be far more efficient.  Get all the data needed for a use case at once in one network round trip.  All that traffic must be a performance killer.

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is to use the smallest possible scope of a given variable. You should always try to use the request scope first and use the session scope only when the request is not enought.